# Add data in a grid made out of divs

Tags: html, angular

I created a grid made out of divs, and want to add data into these grids, how can I do this with `*ngFor` , or is there a better solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by below,

```
<!-- Angular -->
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{i}} {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```

here `items` is array of your items to shown in div

you can perform same thing with `ng-repeat` in Angular 1.x

```
<!-- Angular 1.x -->
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{$index}} {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```